# Changing the local variable of a function from within another function that is defined in said function.. Python

Tags: python, function, variables, global, local

Is there a way to access the local variable of a function from a function that is defined within said function?
Y is a tuple with strings, and I want whatever caps becomes when a condition is met to stay the same for the next call with the next item in y. I tried to use the built-in function global, but I guess that only works for globals.

```
def cap_sentence(y):  
    caps = "on"  
    def func(x):  
        if caps == "on"
            caps = "off"
            return x.capitalize()
        elif "." in x:
            caps = "on"
    return tuple(map(func, y))
```

Comment: Accessing, let alone changing variables in another scope is almost never a good idea. Can you explain what your code is supposed to do? There's surely a better way.

Comment: @thg435, often it makes sense for closures. That's why nonlocal was added to Python3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`nonlocal`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=nonlocal#the-nonlocal-statement) in Python 3.x:

```
def cap_sentence(y):  
    caps = "on"  

    def func(x):  
        nonlocal caps 
        if caps == "on":
            caps = "off"
            return x.capitalize()
        elif "." in x:
            caps = "on"

    return tuple(map(func, y))
```

In python 2.7:

```
def cap_sentence(y):  
    cap_sentence.caps = "on"  

    def func(x):  
        if cap_sentence.caps == "on":
            cap_sentence.caps = "off"
            return x.capitalize()
        elif "." in x:
            cap_sentence.caps = "on"

    return tuple(map(func, y))
```

Comment: @KingJames For more `python 2.x` options, you can see some solutions [here](http://goo.gl/jYhW9)

Comment: Interesting solution! I might be inclined to make `caps` a "private" variable in the second version -- `cap_sentence._caps`.

Answer (score 0):

Although using `nonlocal` is the direct answer to your question, I would encourage you to consider using a callable class here. This avoids re-defining a function every time `cap_sentence` is called, and it handles state a more obvious way (to me, anyway). I've taken the liberty of adding a return statement at the end, so that you don't get a string of `None` values.

```
class _CapSentence(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.caps = 'on'
    def capitalize(self, x):
        if self.caps == 'on':
            self.caps = 'off'
            return x.capitalize()
        elif '.' in x:
            self.caps = 'on'
        return x
    def __call__(self, y):
        return tuple(map(self.capitalize, y))

cap_sentence = _CapSentence()

print cap_sentence("my feet are cold. my toes are sandwiches.".split())

# output: ('My', 'feet', 'are', 'cold.', 'My', 'toes', 'are', 'sandwiches.')
```